# Need to change PATH for Git upgrade

Tags: ruby, git, bash, heroku, homebrew

When I run `echo $PATH` I get:

```
/usr/local/heroku/bin:/Users/<my account>/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/bin:/Users/<my account>/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@global/bin:/Users/<my account>/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/Users/<my account>/.rvm/bin
```

I'm pretty sure the /usr/local/heroku/bin is not supposed to be first and I cannot figure out how to edit the path with Vim.

I receive this error from brew doctor in regards to Git.

```
Warning: /usr/bin occurs before /usr/local/bin
```

This means that system-provided programs will be used instead of those
provided by Homebrew. The following tools exist at both paths:

```
git
git-cvsserver
git-receive-pack
git-shell
git-upload-archive
git-upload-pack

Consider setting your PATH so that /usr/local/bin
occurs before /usr/bin. Here is a one-liner:
    echo export PATH='/usr/local/bin:$PATH' >> ~/.bash_profile
```

Obviously I have tried implementing the "one-liner" but it does nothing:

When I run `brew upgrade git` I receive:

```
Error: git 2.2.1 already installed
```

but when I run `git --version` I get:

```
git version 1.9.3 (Apple Git-50)
```

Comment: `echo export PATH='/usr/local/bin:$PATH' >> ~/.bash_profile` Use double quotes, this adds $PATH to the path without expanding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the order your path is being searched:

```
/usr/local/heroku/bin
/Users/<my account>/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/bin
/Users/<my account>/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@global/bin
/Users/<my account>/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/bin
/usr/bin
/bin
/usr/sbin
/sbin
/usr/local/bin
/Users/<my account>/.rvm/bin
```

You're going to have some problems:

- Your RVM initialization isn't occurring last, so RVM will start complaining at some point.
- Your /usr/bin is before /usr/local/bin.

Look inside your ~/.bashrc and ~/.bash_profile for commands/lines that modify your PATH. Adjust those so:

- RVM is the last thing initialized or that can modify your path.
- /usr/local/bin is immediately followed by /usr/bin to allow commands you've added to override the system ones.
- Paths that are exclusive to specific things, like the Heroku path, can be last *unless* their commands are the same as ones in /usr/local/bin:/usr/bin. In that case, add the Heroku path immediately before /usr/local/bin.

You don't have to use Vim to edit if you don't understand how to use it. Instead, try using `pico` or `nano` to edit since those are installed by default on Mac OS X, and are simple to use. (But for the long term learn how to use Vim because it's one of the most powerful editors on the planet, and is available on almost any OS you could ever use.)

Comment: For some reason when I change the file RVM keeps loading first anyways. I have even totally removed any .rvm scripts form ~.profile  ~/.bash_profile and ~/.bashrc. My path continues to remain     /usr/local/heroku/bin:/Users/robertrice/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/bin:/Users/robertrice/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@global/bin:/Users/robertrice/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/Users/robertrice/.rvm/bin

Comment: any ideas about what specific commands to add I may be missing?

Answer (score 1):

Put this in your `.bashrc` file (be sure to backup, aditing `.bashrc` can be dangerous:

```
export PATH="$PATH:/path/to/dir/to/add"
```

This will add a dir to the `PATH` variable next time you start bash. If you want the dirs to be parsed in a different order you can manually set it. Take for instance that the variable contains `/bin/usr:/usr/` and you'd like `/usr` to precede the other dir, add this to the `.bashrc`:

```
export PATH='/usr:/bin/usr'
```

Note that adding this line is harmless for your  bashrc file so backup might not be necessary after all.

Edit: be sure to restart bash before testing out the changes, they will only be applied once you open a new shell.

Edit2: You can also just execute the line in your command line but then `PATH` will change back to the old value upon opening a new shell.

In a nutshell (pun intended) do this:

```
 echo 'export $PATH=/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/heroku/bin:/Users/robertrice/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/bin:/Users/robertri‌​ce/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@global/bin:/Users/robertrice/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:usr/bin:/Users/robertrice/.rvm/bin' >> ~/.bashrc
```